# What is the equivalent of CONFIG_MORE_COMPILE_OPTIONS and CONFIG_COMPILE_OPTIONS for 3.x and 4.x kernels?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, compiling

I'm trying to pass some extra flags to Kbuild, with a 2.6 kernel I can go for

```
CONFIG_MORE_COMPILE_OPTIONS
CONFIG_COMPILE_OPTIONS
```

but with modern kernels there are no such flags, what I should use instead ?

Comment: What exactly did those do?

Comment: @Jan they enable you to manipulate the set of flags passed on to the compiler and the customization happens during the configuration phase, which is probably a better idea than manipulating `make` environment variables "on the fly" or editing the Makefile on your own .